# Exploding Map keys as Column names

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, multiple-columns

I've been struggling with this for a while and can't wrap my head around it. So far I've only found examples which `explode()` a `MapType` column to `n` Row entries.

What I'm trying to achieve is having, for example, a Map with 5 entries as 5 columns within the same Row.

Taking this DF as an example...

```scala
case class SampleRow(one: String, two: String, three: String, four: String, five: Map[String, String])       
val df = List(
          SampleRow(
            "one", 
            "two", 
            "three", 
            "four", 
            Map("sample_one" -> "hey", "sample_two" -> "hey"))
        ).toDF()
```

After exploding column `five`, it should become

| one | two | three | four | sample_one | sample_two |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | two | three | four | hey | hey |

What I tried until now is the following.

```scala
val explodedDS = originDS
      .select(cols :+ $"key".as("outerMap") :+ $"value.*":_*) // Column 'value' as a previous Map has been exploded before
```

But doing that prompts the following error into the console.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer(value)`;

I understand that exploding a Map to Columns generates the issue of not being able to infer a schema until all Row objects contain the exact same number of Columns, either null or with a value, right?

But apart from that, would there be any option to accomplish this despite the schema problem?

Comment: Does the `Map` in each record have the same structure? The same number and name of keys?

Comment: Yes it does @TravisHegner, I prefer to avoid the StructType with all its inner fields specified to make it more flexible but each of the records will have consistency across them.

Comment: can you please reformat your output in a table  structure. It helps better understand what is expected.

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally just edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the fastest, but seems to work:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

case class SampleRow(one: String, two: String, three: String, four: String, five: Map[String, String])
implicit def enc: Encoder[SampleRow] = Encoders.product[SampleRow]

val df = spark.createDataset(List(
          SampleRow(
            "one", 
            "two", 
            "three", 
            "four", 
            Map("sample_one" -> "hey", "sample_two" -> "hey"))
        ))

df.select($"*", explode($"five"))
  .groupBy("one", "two", "three", "four")
  .pivot("key")
  .agg(first($"value"))
  .show()
```

This results in the desired output of:

```
+---+---+-----+----+----------+----------+
|one|two|three|four|sample_one|sample_two|
+---+---+-----+----+----------+----------+
|one|two|three|four|       hey|       hey|
+---+---+-----+----+----------+----------+
```

This may not be perfectly generalized for your actual use case, but it should be close enough to make workable.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach dynamically creating the schema for struct and exploding it to columns.

```scala
val json_col = to_json($"five")
val json_schema = spark.read.json(df.select(json_col).as[String]).schema

val df2 = df.withColumn("five", from_json(json_col, json_schema))
val df3 = df2.select("*", "five.*").drop("five")

df3.show()
// +---+---+-----+----+----------+----------+
// |one|two|three|four|sample_one|sample_two|
// +---+---+-----+----+----------+----------+
// |one|two|three|four|       hey|       hey|
// +---+---+-----+----+----------+----------+
```